# Probability functions and parenthesis in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, probability, finance

I think I might have starred myself blind on this problem. It shouldn't be that hard.

I have made all the components of the equation work separately but something is not working - is my declarations of variables or the function itself?

For now, I am just trying to get it to output a number :/

this function works fine

```
Function d(K, a1, b1)
d = (-Log(K) + a1 + b1 * b1) / b1
End Function
```

this one does not (both functions are included in the same module):

```
Function LN_Call(r As Double, t As Double, K As Double, w As Double, a1 As Double, b1        As Double, a2 As Double, b2 As Double) As Double

Dim d1 As Double
Dim d2 As Double
Dim d3 As Double
Dim d4 As Double
Dim temp1 As Double
Dim temp2 As Double
Dim result As Double

d1 = d(K, a1, b1)
d2 = d1 - b1
d3 = d(K, a1, b1)
d4 = d3 - b2

temp1 = Exp(a1 + b1 * b1 / 2)
temp2 = Exp(a2 + b2 * b2 / 2)

LN_Call = Exp(-r * t) * (w * (temp1 * Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(d1) - K *     Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(d2)) + (1 - w) * (temp2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(d3) - K *            Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(d4)))

End Function
```

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: how exactly it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the function d() is not defined in your line:

```
d1 = d(K, a1, b1)
```

unless included in the **same module.**

If it is included, then:

```
=LN_Call(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

returns:

**1.301699209**

Is this result O.K.?

Comment: Thanks - I guess it is my input's that are wrong... A bit odd though :/